# JavaFX 8 update TableView after new Data added

Tags: javafx, tableview, observablelist

My TableView is not updating, do i need a listener ?
(m is my Model)

```
@FXML
private TableView<Mitarbeiter> mitarbeiter;

ObservableList<Mitarbeiter> data =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(m.getMitarbeiterListe()
                );

mitarbeiter.setItems(data);

public ArrayList getMitarbeiterListe(){
    return mitarbeiterliste;
}
```

In a new Stage i add some Mitarbeiter to the List in my Model

```
m.addMitarbeiterToList(mitarbeiter)

public void addMitarbeiterToList(Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter){
    mitarbeiterliste.add(mitarbeiter);
}
```

But the TableView in the other Stage is not updating the new data.
In the end, is the ObservableList not pointed to the ArrayList from the Model ?

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused, does any data at all show in the table at any point? If so, I'm a little surprised since no columns have been defined for the table. check out this tutorial for more info on table views and how they interact with tableColumns: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/

Comment: i cut that out, there are Columns in the table and the table is working fine. when i change values from existing data inside my model the TableView is updating the values, but when i add new data to the ArrayList in my model, the TableView is not showing the newly added one

Comment: Ahhh, ok I think I see the confusion. as per the docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html mutations to the underlying list are NOT reported to the wrapping observable list. Instead you have to perform operations on the observable list itself, rather than the underlying data structure

Comment: That's it, thank you for the Link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding items to `mitarbeiterliste` (which is an `ArrayList`, and is not observable), add them to `data`, which is the `ObservableList` holding the items for the table. The `TableView` observes this list and automatically updates the view when the list contents changes.

The context of your code snippets is not very clear, but you would do something like

```
public ArrayList getMitarbeiterListe(){
    return data;
}
```

or instead of

```
mitarbeiterliste.add(mitarbeiter);
```

do

```
data.add(mitarbeiter);
```

Comment: hm, okay, and why is the TableView updating when i change values from exisiting elements in the ArrayList ?

Comment: Looks like you figured this out by the time I saw the comment. For completeness: the `ObservableList` is a *wrapper* for the underlying `ArrayList` that adds notification. So both lists point to the same collection of elements, but changes made to the `ObservableList` will notify any observers, including the `TableView`. If you change the underlying `ArrayList`, the data has changes, but the `TableView` might not know it has to repaint. If you change the `ObservableList`, you change the same data, but it will also notify the `TableView` that data has changed.